# Move oracle Column ID

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Suppose I have this table:

[image]

What I want to happen is to move/change the column id of `STATUS_DT` to 10 and adjust the the rest downwards like this:

```
Column Name | ID

...

STAT_ID     | 10
STATUS_DT   | 10
CREA_BY     | 11
CREA_DT     | 12
LAST_UPD_BY | 13
LAST_UPD_DT | 14
```

Is there a single query (`ALTER TABLE`) so that I can achieve this without re-creating the table?

Comment: AFAIK, no. I'm sure you can't if there is data in the table.

Comment: The order of columns in a relational table is irrelevant.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Logically, yes, physically, no.

Comment: @wolφi: it's also physically irrelevant.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Only if the average and total row length is irrelevant.

Comment: I agree with @FlorinGhita, but the problem here is that I am working on `DEV` environment. That means I don't need to worry about the data. I want to create a single `.sql` file to "patch" the table/s. On that way, I only have to instruct our database admin to run that script.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, *The order of columns in a relational table is irrelevant.* means nothing to me. I'm sorry but if you know the `N-tier` method, I have to define the objects on a *certain layer*. It is *my standard* that the last 4 column must be `CREA_BY`,`CREA_DT`, `LAST_UPD_BY`, and `LAST_UPD_DT`.

Comment: You can always re-arrange the order of columns in a select (or a view) therefor the physical order is not important. In the relational model the tuples `(foo, bar)` and `(bar, foo)` are identical (foo and bar being the colum names, not values) - although SQL doesn't treat them that way. Your "requirement" that those columns should come "last" is only an aesthetical requirement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: If you have lost of columns and long columns, one row might not fit into a single database block. How many blocks need to be visited depends then on the physical order of the columns, right?

Comment: @ChristianMark: Do you have a pointer to the `N-tier` method you mentioned?

Comment: @wolφi Nope. But I do have objects. I'm using ASP.NET and C#.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that isn't aesthetical requirements. If you are working on a database with 250+ tables maybe, just maybe you will understand.

Comment: I'm regularly working with databases much larger than that. And I consider it to be an aesthetical  requirement.

Comment: @wolφi: the `LONG` datatype is deprecated since Oracle 8i and should not be used any more. Row-chaining can happen with any physical order of columns.

Comment: Agreed with @a_horse. Anyone who thinks the order of columns in a table matters at all, are either working with a broken DBMS, or don't understand the RM.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, I am a front-end programmer but I understand what RM is. and FYI sir our db is in 5NF so I am confident that the design is *almost* perfect. What I want lies only for the benefit of my coding convention for faster development. All my *objects* for database tables has the standards with regards to the sequence (ID) of the column. But I appreciate your comment. Thank you.

Comment: In that case, change your coding convention.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Just had time to measure the effect of the phys pos of a column in the extremely rowchained table: 1st row 49 consistent gets, 10th 134, 100th 2479, 999th column 23848 consistent gets. Being at the end of a long chain is no fun!

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: At work I'd seriously consider reordering the columns if there are 50+ mostly NULL columns (sigh!), and somebody added later on a NOT NULL column, so forcing all the empty columns to be written out in the row (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#sthref211)

Comment: @wolφi: I understand that row chaining slows down things, but chained rows are not an immediate result of some specific column order (and definitely not an order where the "metadata" columns have to be at the end)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not the immediate result, but it's good for frequently accessed columns to be at the front of any chain, isn't it? Likewise, I'd certainly put the primary key column before and lengthy column, for instance XMLType etc...

Comment: @wolφi, I get your point about the NULL columns followed by a NON-NULL column, but I'd consider it a pretty exceptional scenario where changing the order of the columns makes any appreciable difference to storage use or performance. NULLs don't take up much space in a row. If you were talking about a table with 5M rows and 100 columns, all NULL, and then adding a 101st NON-NULL column, AND you were on a pre-11g database (where adding a non-null column requires an update on each row), then maybe I'd look at alternatives like recreating the table or doing an online redefinition, if needed.

Comment: Guys maybe we can discuss this on chat. Let's open up a topic.=D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory, you could

1. rename the columns to be moved
2. add new columns to the end of the column list
3. copy data from old columns to new columns
4. drop the old columns

In practice, I'd rename the old table and recreated it with the new column order. If need be, with an online reorg...

EDIT: For example:

```
01 INVOICE_REQUEST_ID
   ...
09 STAT_ID
10 CREA_BY
11 CREA_DT
12 LAST_UPD_BY
13 LAST_UPD_DT
14 STATUS_DT
```

Then step 1) rename the columns to be moved:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME COLUMN crea_by     TO tmp_crea_by;
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME COLUMN crea_dt     TO tmp_crea_dt;
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME COLUMN last_upd_by TO tmp_last_upd_by;
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME COLUMN last_upd_dt TO tmp_last_upd_dt;

01 INVOICE_REQUEST_ID
...
09 STAT_ID
10 TMP_CREA_BY
11 TMP_CREA_DT
12 TMP_LAST_UPD_BY
13 TMP_LAST_UPD_DT
14 STATUS_DT
```

Step 2) Add columns to the end of the column list:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME COLUMN crea_by     TO tmp_crea_by;
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME COLUMN crea_dt     TO tmp_crea_dt;
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME COLUMN last_upd_by TO tmp_last_upd_by;
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME COLUMN last_upd_dt TO tmp_last_upd_dt;

01 INVOICE_REQUEST_ID
   ...
09 STAT_ID
10 TMP_CREA_BY
11 TMP_CREA_DT
12 TMP_LAST_UPD_BY
13 TMP_LAST_UPD_DT
14 STATUS_DT
15 CREA_BY
16 CREA_DT
17 LAST_UPD_BY
18 LAST_UPD_DT
```

Step 3) copy data from old columns to new columns:

```
UPDATE my_table 
   SET tmp_crea_by     = crea_by,
       tmp_crea_dt     = crea_dt,
       tmp_last_upd_by = last_upd_by,
       tmp_last_upd_dt = last_upd_dt;
```

Step 4) drop the old columns:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table SET UNUSED (tmp_crea_by, tmp_crea_dt, tmp_last_upd_by, tmp_last_upd_dt);
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;

01 INVOICE_REQUEST_ID
   ...
09 STAT_ID
10 STATUS_DT
11 CREA_BY
12 CREA_DT
13 LAST_UPD_BY
14 LAST_UPD_DT
```

If the data is not relevant, you can skip steps 1) rename and step 3) copy. The script would look like:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table SET UNUSED (crea_by, crea_dt, last_upd_by, last_upd_dt);
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (crea_by     VARCHAR2(30));
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (crea_dt     DATE);
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (last_upd_by VARCHAR2(30));
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (last_upd_dt DATE);
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;
```

Comment: Can I put this on a single file that I can run directly to the server?

Comment: Ah. I see so I just have to put them all in one `.sql` file?

Comment: Exactly. It doesn't need to be run on the server, the DBA can execute the script from his/her client, too.

Comment: Let me try this on our dev server.

Comment: Don't forget the NOT NULL constraints if there are any. It would then be `ADD (crea_by VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL);`

Comment: I see. I'll just alter and add the constraints. Thank you wolφi.=D

Comment: I added a bounty since I use this until now.=D

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you considered just creating a new table in the format you'd like and then moving the data over, dropping the old table and then renaming the new one to the old name?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in: "Step 2) Add columns to the end of the column list:"
The commands are the same of the Step 1, when they should be like this:

- `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD crea_by VARCHAR2(30);`
- ...

Comment: Answer could use a little more detail to be helpful.